# ASP.NET sass/scss compilation at run-time and at compile-time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sass

I am searching for a solution for compiling my .scss files at run-time and at compile-time.

The reason I need both is that our designers work on Macs and prefer the ease of having their .scss files compiled dynamically at run-time (especially during a development phase). On the other hand, I need compile-time support to validate that the SCSS compiles successfully during my build process. My goal is to fail a build if the SCSS doesn't compile.

I have found several libraries available on NuGet, however, minor flaws in each of them are holding me back.

**Is there a solution available for both of these scenarios?**

Here's where my research has led me:

Run-time Support

- **[BundleTransformer.SassAndScss](http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/)** via HttpHandler (works with [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/), albeit very slow)
- **[Cassette.Sass](http://nuget.org/packages/Cassette.Sass/2.0.0)** (unable to compile Bourbon due to [error](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette/issues/377))

Compile-time support:

- **[Cassette.MSBuild](http://nuget.org/packages/Cassette.MSBuild/2.0.0)** (Does not appear to bundle SCSS files, only CSS)
- [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) (Pro version apparently includes a command-line tool, however, documentation is very limited on the feature)
- Others?

Comment: It's seems you're still early into your adoption of SASS. Have you thought of using Compass or are you to invested in Bourbon to consider changing? http://compass-style.org/

Comment: Go for `compass watch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pro edition of the [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) includes a command-line tool for compiling at runtime. Currently, only the nightly build is capable of compiling Bourbon and Neat (one of my requirements).

Here is my pre-build event which is working great at the moment:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mindscape\Web Workbench\Command Line\wwcmd.exe"
"$(ProjectDir)scss\style.scss" /o:../css /style:compressed
```

UPDATE:

We decided to simply call SASS from a pre-build event as opposed to using Web Workbench.

```
call sass -C "$(ProjectDir)assets\scss\main.scss" "$(ProjectDir)assets\css\compiled\main.css" --style compressed
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SassAndCoffee](https://github.com/paulcbetts/SassAndCoffee). It's what Cassette is using and it embeds everything into a few assemblies.

Web Workbench on the other hand actually installs ruby and the sass gems to the file system in a very long folder path hidden beneath the current users directory, which is likely to be troublesome for a web application and with respect to security and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Core you can use this package to compile scss at build time and it includes a watcher for debug-time and hot-reloading.

**AspNetCore.SassCompiler**

Sass Compiler Library for .NET Core 3.1/5.x./6.x without node.

https://github.com/koenvzeijl/AspNetCore.SassCompiler

```
# Package Manager
PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.SassCompiler

# .NET CLI
dotnet add package AspNetCore.SassCompiler
```