# Is there any way to compile scss file from code in .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sass

I am trying to develop theme customization for .Net MVC project. I am using sass for styles. I am able to edit variable scss file from Code but scss files are not getting compiled at runtime. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: SCSS compiled into plain CSS by a different compiler than .NET. But this link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598143/asp-net-sass-scss-compilation-at-run-time-and-at-compile-time

Answer (score 3):

as per my suggestion install one Extension in VS name is "Web Compiler". I am using same since 10 months and its working fine.

Here is the link you can go step by step:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

Comment: I have this installed but while building the project it works fine but its not compiling when I add new variable file from front-end when project is live

Comment: for this you need to compile whole style.scss once while live your project. sometime its not working on my case as well. So, i compile whole style.scss. if i get anything regarding that i will post here. 

Keep Coading :)